# Help solving an RL circuit with no switch included

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm trying to solve this RL circuit to find i<sub>0</sub>(t) for all t values, but I've never seen a schematic without a switch included.

I'm lost on how to approach the question when I don't know where exactly the circuit would be open or closed. Any help would be great.

[image: RL circuit example given without a switch]

Comment: What does u(t) mean to you? Is this problem to be solved entirely in the time domain using differential equation methods? Or are you prepared for Laplace? (Though I admit I worry already, since you wrote, *"I don't know where exactly the circuit would be open or closed"*, and this implies you don't follow u(t) which implies 'biting off more than you can chew'.) Community level course or university?

Comment: As far as I know, we shouldn't need Laplace transforms and should be able to stay in the time domain. We are supposed to use the equation for tau = L/R and i0(t) = A + Be^(-t/tau) but I'm not sure where to start in order to even use those equations. I could very well be misunderstanding, but it wasn't explained well to me in the first place so I'm hoping there is a better explanation out there.

Comment: Thanks. It helps to understand more about where you are positioned. To start, you need to understand Oliver Heaviside's meaning for u(t). What do you know about it? It's not a difficult idea. But you do need to know what it means or else you cannot read that schematic, properly.

Comment: I know it's a step function of sorts, but that's about it. I'm just not sure if (in this case) it would imply V=0 @ t<=0 and V=120 @ t>0 or if it's something else entirely.

Comment: It's 0 when t < 0 and 1 when t > 0. (It's not defined for u(t=0) for math-technical reasons you don't need to worry about.) So in this case you are to assume that the circuit voltage source is at 60 V * 0 = 0 V for a long time. Then at t=0, thereabouts, it jumps to 60 V * 1 = 60 V for all of t > 0. So that's your switch event giving you a *before* and an *after*. You also may want to simplify the schematic for analysis purposes. Are you comfortable doing that? (It may help a lot.)

Comment: Ok, so then the i0(t) for t<0 would be 0A? since there is no voltage flowing through the circuit. Or am I thinking of it wrong in that case? Making equivalent circuits aren't my strong suit but I'll try it out

Comment: Yeah. I think that's likely correct. ;) Also, you can convert the 0.4*i0 into a resistance since it is in parallel to the current it depends upon and there's only resistance in that other branch. Can you do that? What if I replaced that dependent current source with an 35/0.4=87.5 Ohm resistor, for example? Would it change the circuit behavior?

Comment: You can combine the resistors in parallel and make one 25 ohm resistor in its place?

Comment: Yes! The whole thing starts simplifying really fast. Because now you have a resistor divider and you can create a Thevenin equivalent for the source and that divider. So now it is just a source, a resistor, and an inductor. Which I suspect you've already got the equation for... Work on becoming flexible about your ways of looking and seeing. Practice redrawing schematics. It will pay off. (I am sorry to hear that things are not being explained well.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I genuinely had no idea how to convert the current source so I appreciate you telling me that trick.

Comment: It just adds a tool you can apply, at times. But it points to a general idea, too, which is that you need to develop skill in looking for similar 'symmetries.' This is by no means the only one. There are situations where the symmetries are the same but the units are different (amps instead of ohms, volt-seconds instead of volts, etc.) Once you get tuned in to the idea, generally, you'll starting finding these things in a variety of different places and painted differently, but still solvable by using the same basic idea for simplifying groups of parts for analysis purposes. Practice!

Answer (score -1):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm6amI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_3&=\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_1\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}&=\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{I}_2\$:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_4\right)\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)\left(1+\text{n}\right)\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{n}\right)\right)}\tag4$$

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lower case letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

- $$\text{R}_4=\text{sL}\tag5$$
- The input voltage is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}\tag6$$

So, we get:

$$\text{i}_2\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}_1+\text{sL}\right)\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}}{\text{s}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\left(\text{R}_3+\text{sL}\right)\left(1+\text{n}\right)\right)+\text{sL}\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{n}\right)\right)}\tag7$$

Now, when we use inverse Laplace transform (using your values) we can see:

$$\text{I}_2\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{12\left(2000+\text{s}\right)}{\text{s}\left(16400+11\text{s}\right)}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\frac{12}{451}\cdot\left(55-14\exp\left(-\frac{16400t}{11}\right)\right)\tag8$$

---

I used the following mathematica-code to solve this question:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
R1 = 10;
R2 = 20;
R3 = 15;
R4 = s*5*10^(-3);
Vi = 60/s;
n = 4/10;
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[
  I2 /. Solve[{I3 == n*I2 + I2, n*I2 == I0 + I1, I4 == I0 + I2, 
      I3 == I1 + I4, I1 == V2/R1, I2 == (Vi - V1)/R2, 
      I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == V2/R4}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, V1, 
      V2}][[1]], s, t]]

Out[1]=12/451 (55 - 14 E^(-16400 t/11))
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? Thanks a lot.

Comment: All downvotes and upvotes should be disclosed. Anonymous up and down voting may avoid hurt feelings expanding into a 'war'. But if it turns into a war of any kind, those who stay around will know who is who and who is doing what. And I think that's a good thing, not a bad thing. All swords have two sides -- they cuts two ways no matter how you go. But I think the "no anonymous up or down voting" sword is the better sword of the two. For down votes, it would also be both courageous and appropriate to provide a comment explaining them. Doesn't have to be long. Cowardice is a vice, not a virtue.